# UISwipeGestureRecognizer detecting swiped object

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to call a method when a UItextView is being slided on, and determine its tag. I was using this code:

```
-(IBAction)donecomment:(id)sender{

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *myLongPressRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(holdpress:)];
[textname addGestureRecognizer:myLongPressRecognizer];

textname.editable = NO;
textname.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

CGRect frame = textname.frame;
frame.size.height = textname.contentSize.height;
textname.frame = frame;

heightInteger = heightInteger + textname.contentSize.height + 6;

[textnameArray addObject:textname];

addComment.hidden = NO;
doneComment.hidden = YES;
cancelComment.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)holdpress:(id)sender{

UITextView *txtChoosen = (UITextView*) sender;

for (UITextView* txt in textnameArray) {
    if (txt.tag == txtChoosen.tag) {

        txt.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
        txt.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    }else{

        txt.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
        txt.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
}}
```

...I get this error: reason: '-[PhotoViewController holdpress]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x22c1a000'

I think I can solve it using:

```
- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
```

...but using htis means removing the sender. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution:

```
-(IBAction)donecomment:(id)sender{

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *myLongPressRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipe:)];
 //[myLongPressRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
[textname addGestureRecognizer:myLongPressRecognizer];

textname.editable = NO;
textname.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

CGRect frame = textname.frame;
frame.size.height = textname.contentSize.height;
textname.frame = frame;

heightInteger = heightInteger + textname.contentSize.height + 6;

[textnameArray addObject:textname];

addComment.hidden = NO;
doneComment.hidden = YES;
cancelComment.hidden = YES;

}

- (void)leftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

id sender;
UITextView *txtChoosen = (UITextView*) sender;

for (UITextView* txt in textnameArray) {
    if (txt.tag == txtChoosen.tag) {

        txt.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
        txt.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    }else{

        txt.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
        txt.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
}}
```

Comment: How is this any different than what you had? All you did was rename the method from `holdpress:` to `leftSwipe:`. Of course your assignment of `txtChoosen` is terribly broken.

Comment: What do you suggest doing?

Comment: Get rid of `sender` and update `txtChoosen` to: `UITextView *txtChoosen = (UITextView *)recognizer.view;`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is complaining about a method named `holdpress`. In the code you posted you have a method named `holdpress:`. Note the difference - the method has a colon, the error method doesn't.

Also in the code you posted you setup the gesture recognizer to use the selector for `holdpress:`. This properly matches the method you actually have. That is correct.

Since the error is about `holdpress` and not `holdpress:`, you must have some other code that tries to use the `holdpress` selector instead of `holdpress:`.

Is the posted code from `PhotoViewController`?

Search your code for calls to `holdpress` (not `holdpress:`).

Comment: No, I only have 1 holdpress

Comment: Where is it? That's the problem. You need `holdpress:`, not `holdpress`.

Comment: and thats the only call to holdpress, from the gesture swipe

Comment: No, the one in the question is not `holdpress`, it is `holdpress:`.

Comment: Ok, what I am saying is that I only have that method called holdpress

Comment: No other method in that .m file has the word holdpress in it

Comment: Did you copy the error correctly when you posted this question? Does the error reference `holdpress` or `holdpress:`?

Comment: As you see it in the question

Comment: Actually, it's ok, I solved the problem by taking out the id sender from the method, and it works.! i didn't know you could do that, see my ans